# Cannot pass function of type '() async throws -> Bool' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

Tags: swift, asynchronous, boolean

I am running this code in Swift:

```
        async {[weak self] () -> Bool in
            
            return true
        }
        //.then{ [weak self] isError in
        //}
        //.onError{ [weak self] error in
        //}
```

But get an error below:

`Cannot pass function of type '() async throws -> Bool' to parameter expecting synchronous function type`

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't have an older swift version, however because `async` is deprecated on my system, swift 5.5, I would use:
`Task { () -> Bool in  return true  }`.